# how to recognise capital letters and not just lower case

Tags: java

Hi i have done this program it works fine except if the user tries to write in capital letters i tried .toUpperCase but it still closes the program if you try to use capital letter to search  can anyone help please thank you

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class database
    {
       static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       //my arrays
       static String country [] = new String[1000];
       static String capital [] = new String[1000];
       static double population [] = new double[1000];

       static List<String> countriesList = Arrays.asList (country); //a new array for user to add data to

      public static void main (String args [])throws IOException
       {
           // now i am adding data to the arrays
           country[0] = "Barbados";
           capital[0] = "Bridgetown";
           population[0] = 65.3;
           country[1] = "france";
           capital[1] = "paris";
           population[1] = 315.8;  
           country[2] = "nigeria";
           capital[2] = "abuja";
           population[2] = 170.1;
           country[3] = "USA";
           capital[3] = "washington";
           population[3] = 2840;
           country[4] = "japan";
           capital[4] = "tokoyo";
           population[4] = 126.7;

           int option = 0;  

           System.out.println("WELCOME TO MY COUNTRY DATABASE\n");

                  while(option!= 5){  //Only five options

                   options();
                   option = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                   if(option > 5 || option < 1)
                   {
                   System.out.println("Wrong input! Try Again");   
                   System.out.println("CHOOSE FROM 1 - 5 \n ");
                }

                   if(option ==  1) {
                   addCountry();
                   }
                   else if(option == 2){
                   searchCountry();  //Search from an array
                   }  
                   else if(option == 3){
                   ListCountry();  

                   }
                   else if(option == 4){
                   getFare();  //show fare to travel 
                   }
                   else if(option == 5) {
                   System.out.print("\n Thank you and Goodbye ");

                }
           }
          }

      public static void options()
       {  
           System.out.println("Main menu");  
           System.out.println("=========");
           System.out.println("1. Add a new country");
           System.out.println("2. Search for a country");
           System.out.println("3. Show list of countries available");
           System.out.println("4. Get fare from London to countries listed");
           System.out.println("5. Exit");
           System.out.print("\n Choose an option from 1 - 5: ");
       }

      public static void addCountry()throws IOException
       {  
            System.out.println("\n Adding a country");
            System.out.println("===================");
            System.out.print("Enter name of country: ");
            String countryInput = br.readLine();

            System.out.print("Enter Capital: ");
            String capitalInput = br.readLine();

            System.out.print("Enter population: ");
            String populationInput = br.readLine();

            int spareSlot = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < country.length; i++) // loop so data can be added to arraylist
            {
                if(country[i] == null)
                {
                    spareSlot = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            country[spareSlot] = countryInput;
            capital[spareSlot] = capitalInput;
            population[spareSlot] = Double.parseDouble(populationInput);

            System.out.println("\n You added the country " + countryInput + ", the capital is " + capitalInput + ", with a population of " + populationInput + "\n" );      
            //System.out.println("================================================================================================================");

           }  

      public static void searchCountry() throws IOException
         { 
            Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);//Scanner to obtain input from command window

            String output; 
            int size, i;

            System.out.println("\n Searching countries");
            System.out.println("========================= \n");
            System.out.print("Search a Country: ");  
            output = br.readLine();
            boolean found = false;
            //A loop to search from the array
              for(i = 0; i < country.length; i++)

                 if(output.equals(country[i]))
               {
                  found = true;
                   break;
            }
                  if (found)
                  System.out.println(output + " is found at index " + i +"\n");

                else
                  System.out.println(output + ": This country is not found, choose option 1 to Add country \n");

                  if (output == country[0]) 
                {
                      System.out.println("The capital of "+ output + "is " + capital[1] + " with a population of " + population[3]);
                }
                  if(output == country[1]) {
                      System.out.println("The capital is" + capital[4]);
                }
                 if(output == country[2]) {
                       System.out.println("The capital is" + capital[1]);
                } 
                  if(output == country[3]) {
                       System.out.println("The capital is " + capital[2]);
                }
                  if(output == country[4]) {
                       System.out.println("The capital is " + capital[3]);

                }    
        }

      public static void ListCountry()throws IOException
           {
              for (String c : countriesList)
               {
                   if(c!=null)
                       System.out.println("\n" + c +"\n"); // to list all countries so far in the array
               }   
           }

       public static void getFare()
         {
            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
            String destination;
            int fare;

            System.out.println("\n Get a fare:");
            System.out.println("============== \n");
            System.out.print("Select destination by entering number from 1 -5: \n");
            System.out.println("1 Caribbean");
            System.out.println("2 Europe");
            System.out.println("3 Africa");
            System.out.println("4 America");
            System.out.println("5 Japan");

            destination = input.nextLine();  //get destination from user
            fare = Integer.parseInt(destination);

              switch(fare)
           {

              case 1: System.out.println("To travel to the Carribbean the fare is from £600 \n");
              break;
              case 2: System.out.println("To travel to Europe the fare is from £199 \n");
              break;
              case 3: System.out.println("To travel to Africa the fareis from £500 \n");
              break;
              case 4: System.out.println("To travel to America the fare is from £290 \n");
              break;
              case 5: System.out.println("To travel to Japan the fare is from £550 \n");
              break;
              default: System.out.println("INVALID ACTION START AGAIN \n");
              System.out.println("======================================");
           }
      }
         }
```

Comment: *how to recognise capital letters and not just lower case* - If you recognize lowercase, what's the problem of recognizing capital letters?

Comment: Please get familiar with the concept of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Not just code explain what you're trying to do in code next the problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: i only put my problem up last time and everyone wanted the full program  ill do that now then

Comment: in the search it doesn't recognize capital letters that's the problem i am having it only recognises lower case and if you type an upper case letter the program closes.

Answer (score 0):

You have one comparison reading

```
 if(output.equals(country[i]))
```

If you want this to be case-insensitive, you want to change that to

```
 if(output.equalsIgnoreCase(country[i]))
```

Later in your code, you have lines similar to

```
 if (output == country[0])
```

which compares object identity rather than string equality.  You want to change all these to at least properly compare strings, and possibly to be case-insensitive as above.